# Scrollmagic. Need make navigation links. How scroll to scene progress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

I need to make 4 navigation links for 4 sections. The sections show on scroll by scrollmagic. There is a link for [example code](https://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/section_wipes_manual.html). How scroll to scene progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution on this question, but in russian, who is interesting of this question can visit this site https://qna.habr.com/q/807599 or ask for me